# Laravel 5, why is a redirect to named route in middleware causing "localhost redirected you too many times"

Tags: php, laravel

I have a pretty straight forward middleware:

```
protected $auth;

public function __construct(Guard $auth)
{
    $this->auth = $auth;
}

/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    //dd($this->auth->user());
    if($this->auth->user()->id  && $this->auth->user()->pastDueFees()){
        \Session::flash('message','You must pay past due deal fees before using the rest of the website');
        return redirect()->route('profile.investment-fees');
    } 

    return $next($request);
}
```

This causes the redirect loop.  I am only calling the middleware via Kernel.php.

My Kernal.php:

```
<?php namespace App\Http;
```

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel {

```
/**
 * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middleware = [
    'Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode',
    'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies',
    'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse',
    'Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession',
    'Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession',
    'App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken',
    'App\Http\Middleware\FeesOwed'
];

/**
 * The application's route middleware.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate',
    'auth.signed' => 'App\Http\Middleware\AuthenticateSigned',
    'fees' => 'App\Http\Middleware\FeesOwed',
    'auth.subscribed' => 'App\Http\Middleware\AuthenticateSubscribed',
    'admin' => 'App\Http\Middleware\AuthenticateAdmin',
    'auth.basic' => 'Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth',
    'guest' => 'App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated',
];
```

}

thanks in advance.

Comment: What do your routes look like? This middleware isn't applied to the `profile.investment-fees` route right?

Comment: Not I am not applying it to routes, just adding it as middleware in Kernal.php

Comment: can you show us your kernel file, where you applied  the middleware

Comment: There's your problem. If this is applied to every route then it will be applied to `profile.investment-fees` as well. When you try to redirect to that route it tries to redirect again because `pastDueFees()` hasn't changed

Comment: make sure you added the middleware to only `$routeMiddleware` and not `$middlewareGroups` or `$middleware`

Comment: @jfadich I think thats right, how do I keep it from being applied to that url?

Comment: There are multiple ways to do it. You could have an extra check in your middleware to not redirect if the current page is the profile.investment-fees page. That might be best if this is meant to be on every single page. Otherwise you could change this to a route middleware like EddyTheDoves answer

Comment: @jfadich, your comment is the reason for the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply that middleware to all routes but `profile.investment.fees`. In your kernel, add your middleware in the `$routeMiddleware` array as

```
'alias' => \App\Http\Middleware\MyMiddleware::class,
```

Then in your route define a group containing that middleware, and make sure `profile.investment-fees` is out of it

```
Route::get('pif', 'MyController@pif')->name('profile.investment-fees');

//Route group
Route::group(['middleware' => 'alias'], function(){
    //every other routes that need the middleware
});
```

Alternatively, in your middleware, you could simply avoid that specific route by ignoring it with an if else

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next) {
    if ($request->is('pif')) {
         return $next($request);
    }
    ...
}
```